# Checking the answers and computing the score - JavaScript/HTML

Tags: html

I have about 20 question in this quiz. Now what I'm trying to do is to check whether my answer is correct or not when i submit the form. and print out the score.

```html
1.) What is HTML ?
<br>
<input type="radio" name="ans" value="a"> Hypertext Markup Language<br>
<input type="radio" name="ans" value="b"> Hypertrain Markup Language<br>
<input type="radio" name="ans" value="c"> Hypertext Marking Language<br>
<input type="radio" name="ans" value="d"> HypertraingMarking Language<br><br>

2.) What does GUI mean ?
<br>
<input type="radio" name="ans1" value="a"> Graphics User Interface<br>
<input type="radio" name="ans1" value="b"> Graphical User Internet<br>
<input type="radio" name="ans1" value="c"> Graphical User Interface<br>
<input type="radio" name="ans1" value="d"> Graphics User Internet<br><br>
```

[Jonas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C0XM.png)

Comment: The scoring should not be done on the client side if this is going to be used for anything serious.

Comment: for homework purposes. We're gonna run this on a local computer only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    counter=0;
    score=0;
    function wrong(A){
        A.parentElement.style.display="none";
        counter++;
        score--;
    }
    function right(A){
        A.parentElement.style.display="none";
        counter++;
        score++;
    }
    function print(){
        if(counter==2){
            Alert(score);
        }else{
            alert("You didnt answered everything");
        }
    }

</script>
<div>
    Question1:<br>
    <a href="javascript:right(this)">True</a>
    <a href="javascript:wrong(this)">False</a>
</div>
<a href="javascript:print()">Score</a>
```

This hides the div around the question when an answer is clicked

Comment: Using this, if you click a correct answer multiple times, wouldn't it add +1 each time nevertheless?

Comment: using this. if i would click the answer twice, would it add 2 instead of 1 ?

Comment: Jup. But as its javascript one could also type right() multiple times into the console or could modify the script. So a real safe game is not possible.

Comment: I improved it so that it hides the question after a given answer. The div around the question is imoprtant for that

Comment: Got the idea. but how can you make this in a radio button coz my prof says that we need to use radio buttons. :3 sorry

Comment: @Ceejay Alcomedas : added it as an extda answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function check(name)
    {
        var radios = document.getElementsByName(name);
        for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (radios[i].checked) {
                return parseInt(radios[i].value);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function finish()
    {
        score = 0;
        score = score + check("ans");
        score = score + check("ans1");
        alert(score);
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:finish()">Check</a>
```

Use your inputs but change the values.
True answer value=1
 wrong answer value=0

Comment: trying to do this but nothings happens. I'll try to figure this out. thanks a lot

Comment: What didnt work? Can you describe? Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors. just when i clicked the check nothing happens. It didn't show the score. I already tried to changed the value from a-d to 1 and 0

Comment: Oh there was a } after break; missing.

Comment: Woooot. I think there's an error.

I'll edit my post to upload the error in the picture

How to upload picture in a comment. lol

Comment: You cannot. Edit your question

Comment: Edited. Please check. You're my savior.

Comment: Ive made a mistake, i will update my question, but you made a mistake too. Can you upload your complete code?

Comment: Ive added "parseInt" to improve: 110 to 2

Comment: Cant edit the post. 

sad :( Should i screencapture the code and post it as a picture ?

Comment: You must have added sth there

Comment: figured it out. done already. You have my thanks, sir. I wub you

Comment: No worries :) Could you please mark it as an answer?